# SharePoint fixed table header

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm trying to make my table header fixed, and below it are all the contents that can be scroll.

I want to do something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7878bweOSw

Can anyone please help me out.

By the way, I'm am only a contributor and I can only edit page via browser.

Comment: On which part of SharePoint you have a table which you want to be fixed?

Comment: You can use sticky header plugin. Google stickyheader for SharePoint .I have used it.works weĺl in 2013

Comment: I don't have access to download jQuery, and I only have basic controls in Sharepoint Online. Is there any way that I can implement Freezing headers for my Sharepoint lists?

Answer (score 3):

I've recently used the sticky headers library to add fixed headers to out of the box SharePoint list views.  Works in both standard and quick mode in SharePoint Online.  I put a link to the script in a Script Editor web part on the view where i want this functionality.  I believe you can also add to the master page for cross site implementation.

http://spoodoo.com/sticky-headers-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Would you kinda give direction how to add this js file to the masterpage for cross site use?

Answer (score 1):

It requires adding some CSS to the page, you can put a Content Editor WebPart in the page with
(and hardcode the required height)

```
<STYLE>
    .ms-viewheadertr {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    .ms-listviewtable tbody {
        display: block;
        overflow: auto;
        height: 300px;
    }
</STYLE>
```

For testing I advice using Chrome and the [StyleBot Plugin](http://stylebot.me/about) so you can apply the CSS live in any page.
But if you are the only user you do not need to work it into the page with a CEWP; StyleBot can be your friend on many pages.

iCSS

Comment: +1 This is a brilliantly simple solution that took me 30 seconds to test by making a style bookmarklet at http://www.squarefree.com/userstyles/make-bookmarklet.html.   And, I can use my bookmarlet on ANY Sharepoint 2013 list page as a user!! I can't for the life of me figure out why this wasn't upvoted.  It's also drop dead simple to build a custom web part (using, for instance, the HTML form web part), then export it and upload it to your Web Part Gallery so you can drop it onto any list view page in seconds.

Comment: This doesn't work in quick edit mode